# I cannot use component inside the same library in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, lib, angular-ivy

I'm using angular 13 and I have a test library which contains 2 components: lib1 and lib2.

I want to use lib2 compoment in lib1 component by doing an import of its module in lib1.module

Later on, this library is used in the 'showcase-test' app to check that the library is correctly working.

**Error found:**
The Ivy compiler is always prompting 'Cannot find module '@lib/lib2' or its corresponding declarations'

I attach here the test workspace that I've created to reproduce the error.

https://github.com/ricardmc/workspace-test

I think it's something from configuration and relative paths but I cannot find it.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The url to your github gives a 404 (Page not found)

Comment: If both components are in the same library I think you should use a relative import. Otherwise you introduce a cyclic dependency.

Comment: using './../lib2' path is still failing when launching build command. It works when serving the app locally, but build process throws error.

Also, github link is fixed.

Comment: Ah, I see in your repository that it's an import from a different library, then indeed you should not use relative imports.
Maybe try to define the libs explicitly in tsconfig.json? Instead of using one entry and the * wildcard in "paths": {
      "@lib": ["projects/lib"],
      "@lib/*": ["projects/lib/*"]
    }

Comment: ok, I will try to define all libs in tsconfig.